# Joomla content to pdf

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, joomla2.5

Hi I'm trying to convert a joomla page into pdf so far the things I tried keep failing or fell short. I tried [PhocaPDF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/print-a-pdf/7492/) but I get tons of errors upon install and It would require me to change the jore of joomla. also tried [Root pdf content](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/print-a-pdf/21880/) problem is I have some php codes in the articles that would output too. So I'm only left with hard coding it. Would anyone help me on how should I approach this?  Should I use PHP on my articles or Javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use following extension 
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=624&t=808593